# Remove invalid Named Ranges containing #REF from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

None of the answers I have seen work. They all seem to use some form of SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getNamedRanges() as the driver. This action **does not retrieve** the named ranges containing "#REF". Is there a solution that someone has been successful with or do I need to manually correct the spreadsheets?

Comment: The ranges that contain "#REF!" have an error in the range.  Most likely the sheet they were created in no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function nr() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const arr = ss.getNamedRanges().map(nr => [nr.getName(),nr.getRange().getA1Notation()]).filter(r => r[1]!="#REF!");
  arr.unshift(["Name","Range"]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
12:35:02 PM Notice  Execution started
12:35:02 PM Info    [["Name","Range"],["Range4","H2:AP13"],["Range2","F2:G8"]]
12:35:03 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Spreadsheet Named Ranges

[image]

If you want all of the ranges including ones that have errors in their ranges:

```
function nr() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const arr = ss.getNamedRanges().map(nr => [nr.getName(),nr.getRange().getA1Notation()]);
  arr.unshift(["Name","Range"]);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr))
}

Execution log
12:41:22 PM Notice  Execution started
12:41:23 PM Info    [["Name","Range"],["Range4","H2:AP13"],["Range1","#REF!"],["stopRow","#REF!"],["Range2","F2:G8"],["Range3","#REF!"]]
12:41:24 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Neither of these worked. the result was:

8:51:00 AM Notice Execution started

8:51:01 AM Info [["Name","Range"]]

8:51:01 AM Notice Execution completed

Comment: They both worked for me  without more details I don't think I can help you much

Comment: Perhaps you can supply and image of your named ranges similar to the one I have in my answer

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot figure out how to paste an image into my Comment. Neither CTRL-G nor CTRL-V work for me.

My bad references look just like yours with refName over #REF

What else can I provide?

Comment: This is the result from running 'nr'. No ranges were identified.
>Execution log

9:00:08 AM Notice Execution started

9:00:31 AM Info [["Name","Range"]]

9:00:31 AM Notice Execution completed